# Lifetime of a static variable

Tags: php, joomla

I'm going through a Joomla book, and I came across the following piece of code in the chapter of MVC pattern:

```
class QuizController extends JController
{
    static function &getInstance(/* some PHP code... */)
    {
        // use a static array to store controller instances
        static $instances;

        if (!$instances)
        {
            $instances = array();
        }

        /* some PHP code... */

        // return a reference to the controller
        return $instances[$class];
    }
}
```

What is the lifetime of `$instances`? When is it destroyed?

If it is alive during the lifetime of the request, then declaring `$instances` static doesn't make sense, because this code will be run once.
If it is alive during user session, how does PHP engine knows this?

Comment: i suppose it would be from whenever the function is called and to the end of execution (since it will always be available). unless of course you destroy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is alive during the lifetime of the request, then declaring
>   $instances static doesn't make sense, because this code will be run
>   once.

Yes, the static variable only exists for the duration of the request.  It's a common design pattern to store an object in a static variable if it's expensive to create, or if having multiple copies will cause problems.

It's not necessarily the case that this function only be called once - it will likely be called multiple times, at least on certain pages / for certain modules.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the code, the variable lasts until the script is finished being executed.

Because you can't access the variable from outside that function, and there is no `unset()` call to that variable, it doesn't get destroyed until the end of script execution.